# TableLayout: ldpi displaying incorrect dimensions

Tags: android, xml, layout, tablelayout

Incorrect image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEIBW.png

as this should be diplaying each image in equal height and width, but "Outbox" image is smaller than the right one. What's wrong here? the smae code works fine in mdpi and hdpi

```
<TableLayout  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="@color/Grey">

        <TableRow>
            <FrameLayout 
                android:id="@+id/inboxLargeButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@drawable/inbox_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWeddingDayCheatSheet"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    >
                </View>
                <TextView  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:text="2631"  
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
                    android:gravity="center"  
                    android:textColor="#fff"  
                    android:textSize="50dp" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:id="@+id/outboxLargeButton"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <View android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@drawable/ourbox_normal" 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonWddingDayCheatSheet"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    >
                </View>
                <TextView  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    android:text="0432"  
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
                    android:gravity="center"  
                    android:textColor="#fff"  
                    android:textSize="50dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved now. Just changed the `FrameLayout` property `android:layout_height` for inbox columns to `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct. Try to clean project and run again.

If that doesn't work try setting the `View` height to `match_parent` and the `FrameLayout` height to a fixed height.